# How do you create session variables within a DotNetNuke skin?

Tags: dotnetnuke, session-variables

I'm trying to create a session variable on the home page skin that will return either true or false depending on if the user has previously visited the home page in the current session. I then need to check the value and if this isn't their first time visiting the home page, I need to echo/print javascript.

I've tried

```
Session("HomePageSeen") = "false"
Session["HomePageSeen"] = "false";
```

Also, it's a DNN6 site. My understanding is that DNN6 uses C# instead of VB. However, at the top of my .ascx skin file, there's this line of code:

```
<%@ Control language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" Explicit="True" Inherits="DotNetNuke.UI.Skins.Skin" %>
```

So I'm not sure if I should write this in C# or VB.

I know how I'd do this in PHP and I feel like the same logic would apply here, but I'm no where near as well versed in .Net, VB, or C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The skin can be in either language, in whatever version of DNN that you want (the core code switched to C# in DNN 6, but that doesn't affect the language used by extensions).  The language for the skin is based on that `language` attribute in the [`Control` directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d19c0t4b%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

You should be able to get and set a session value using that `Session` property.  Something like this:

```
<% If Session("HomePageSeen") Is Nothing Then %>
    <% Session("HomePageSeen") = True %>
    <script>alert('hello');</script>
<% End If %>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. [This](http://i.imgur.com/RDzj4.png) is what the page is supposed to look like. When I add your code or any of the code I've previously tried, [this](http://i.imgur.com/Fi56zh.png) happens. Maybe something about my DNN install or web.config is interfering? I'm not sure what else would cause this...

Comment: If the skin switches back to the default like that, it means there was an error loading the skin.  If you're logged in as an administrator, you can see the error (and go to the Log Viewer in the Admin menu to see previous errors)

Comment: The error I was getting was "Value of type 'System.Web.SessionState.HttpSessionState' cannot be converted to 'Boolean'." After looking at your code again, I realized that `Session["HomePageSeen"]` is C#. I changed it to `Session("HomePageSeen")` since my page is being compiled in VB and it works! Thanks so much! :)